# Eclipse C++ project - Running external make file with different targets

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, makefile, external

I have searched for a long while but couldn't find the answer.

I use Eclipse C++, and created a Makefile based project, where all the source code and make file I downloaded from some source. I could build and run the project in terminal (I'm in Mac OS X), by doing "make clean", then "make depend" then "make", and run.

I would like to do these same things, but in eclipse in order to take advantage of its graphical debugging tool, but cannot figure out how to build it using the makefile provided.

here is the details:

makefile is "Makefile", resides in proj/myapp/niki/Makefile (so it's not in the root folder).

I need to be able to do "make clean", then "make depend" then "make" then run it.

I went to project properties in eclipse, in "C/C++ Build" I unselected "Use default build command", and specify the "build command" as "make -f proj/myapp/niki/Makefile". Is there anything wrong with that? and how to I do "make clean", "make depend"...

I didn't use XCode because it dropped the auto-completion when I imported a whole external
source code to XCode project.

Thanks early for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific view that allows to define specific make targets.

If it is not opened in your perspective, you can open it through the following menus : `Window > Show View > Make target`

In this view you can define as many target you want.